# Unable to download artifact from Azure DevOps "IIS Web App Deploy" Task

Tags: iis, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Suddenly my Release pipeline were taking so long to download artifact and never completes it so my option is to only cancel it. I'm using Deployment Group Agent to deploy my .Net Core web app to IIS. Does anyone encountered this issue and any fix to this? I can't see any status or logs on whether it is downloading artifacts, so I totally don't know what is happening. I tried to remove the vsts agent on services then redeploy again a new vsts agent but still unable to download the artifact.

OS: Windows Server 2016
.Net Core APP
IIS 10

[IIS Result, I cancelled it because I'm not sure if it is downloading the artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBoxv.jpg)

[Release Pipeline for IIS using Deployment Group Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXeMS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a network issue. Opening firewall rule port 443 or 8080 for vstsagent might help fix the problem.